# getting unexcepted url

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i have a form and when i do submit i got in url `?captcha=captcha&submit=` complete url  `http://localhost/signup/signup.php?captcha=captcha&submit=` .

1.why i am getting this i have not use php for url

my code is

html

```
   <div id="captcha-input">
           <form class="form-wrapper"><input type="text" name="captcha" value="captcha"/>
           <button  type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>

           </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: try this ;the name is captcha not the id you are using in your code ; add id="captcha" to the input attribute

Comment: Ask yourself this, "Where do I want this form to post to? Can the form read my mind? (Assuming that you realize it can't...) How do I tell my form where to post?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified the `action` attribute on your form so it is being submitted to the current URL that your page was loaded from. If you want it to be posted to a different page change your opening form tag to something like this:

```
<form class="form-wrapper" method="POST" action="<YOUR URL HERE>">
```

Answer (score 1):

These are get-parameters. Set your form method to 'POST' and the parameters will be send using post instead of GET.

Answer (score 1):

Because an empty url inside a form translates to the current page; you can override this by adding an `action` attribute to the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have not written a action attribute as well as method attribute
<div id="captcha-input"> 
           <form class="form-wrapper" method="post" action="some_page.php"><input type="text" name="captcha" value="captcha"/> 
           <button  type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button> 

           </form> 
        </div>
```

By the way where have you invoked function showdiv..